# How to use two network interfaces at same time?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing, network-interface

I have two network interfaces as ppp0 and ppp1.

The "route" output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.65     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
```

There is one default route as you see. So, I want to use spesific route with different programs like that:

```
test1.py --> ppp0 --> internet
test2.py --> ppp1 --> internet
```

Is there any way to do? I think the solution may be proxying over ppp0 and ppp1 interfaces. But how?

Update:

I've found cURL --interface option.

```
curl --interface ppp0 http://test.com
curl --interface ppp1 http://test.com
```

But only one interface works which has default route record.

Comment: @Christopher: Nope, it's not a duplicate of this question - the situation in this question is totally different: here both interfaces are on a single broadcast domain and are point-to-point, there the interfaces are on different broadcast domains and have different gateways. If you'd try to set up policy routing in both cases, you'd end up with very different rules.

Comment: What is the objective?  Failover redundancy?  Higher throughput?  See [Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster Internet](https://superuser.com/q/660798/354511), [Is it possible to combine two internet connections to increase performance?](https://superuser.com/q/239546/354511), and [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?](https://superuser.com/q/240122/354511)

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Bind application programs to a specific interface, as you've done with `curl --interface`.
- Use [policy routing](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/TOC.html).
- Create different network namespaces, put one or both interface(s) into the namespace(s), start application programs that should use that interface in the appropriate namespace.

Since you didn't describe your use case (except "test programs"), I can't say which is the best option for you.

If it's really just test programs, and you wrote the programs yourself, having them bind to an interface is the simplest way.

Comment: Yes, it does not matter what the programs include. You can imagine they just call curl command with interface param.

Comment: The thing is that it matters very much what the programs do, because the *programs* must include the code to bind to a specific interface. Not all programs do that, so you'll have to change the source code if you want a `--interface` option. It also matters very much if you want to use this for testing, or some other purpose: For testing, a command line option is fine; for other circumstances, I'd use a network namespace, and so on.